# apache poi - continue looping after condition has found

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this code and now what I want to do is I want to do checking if this looping has found the ABC01 then it will continue to loop to look for the '2018'. I tried to do checking and increment like in the code, but it wont work. Please help me.

```
public static void ReadFile() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:xx"));
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    for (Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.rowIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            String val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            /* System.out.println(val); */

            if (val.equals("ABC01")) {
                i++;
            }
            if (val.equals("2018")) {
                System.out.print("XX");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if this looping has found the ABC01 then it will continue to loop to look for the '2018'.` -- there is no separate loop for looking for 2018; the code executes the two if conditions one after another in one loop

Comment: if you specifically mention what doesn't work in your code, then it will be easy to answer.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I see. but if i put the second condition inside the the first condition with increment i++ but it still wont work

Comment: Why are you looking for these two values - what is your problem statement?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I have multiple columns and rows inside my excel file. and now I loop all the data and in the same time I want to look for ABC01 and 2018 in order for me to output the XX

Comment: @Ravi I have multiple columns and rows inside my excel file. and now I loop all the data and in the same time I want to look for ABC01 and 2018 in order for me to output the XX

Comment: So you are looking for ABC01 and 2018 in the whole excel file. What happens if there are multiple occurrences of them and that too far apart?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh supposedly the loop will continue to look for the next condition until it finally found?

Comment: and if there is another instance of ABC01  before that or multiple instances of ABC01   before that?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh in my excel file, the ABC01 and 2018 are both in the same row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181734/discussion-between-sharky-and-balwinder-singh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, the following code should work for you

```
public static void ReadFile() throws Exception {
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:xx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = null;
XSSFCell cell = null;

DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String val;

for (Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.rowIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
        cell = row.getCell(i);           
        val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
        /* System.out.println(val); */

        if (val.equals("ABC01")) {
            i++;

            cell = row.getCell(i);
            val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            if (val.equals("2018")) {
                System.out.print("XX");
            }
        }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this code works. Thank you mates. I really appreciate your time for me.

Comment: Cheers @sharky.